# How to draw boxes around table elements being displayed on the webpage using Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm trying out Django for the first time as a web framework.

My views.py function looks as follow:

```
def display(request):
    find_duplicate()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'obj': my_model.objects.order_by('id')})

def get_dict():
    d={}
    for e in my_model.objects.all():
        col2 = e.col2
        col3 = e.col3
        col2 = unicode(col2).encode('UTF8')
        col3 = unicode(col3).encode('UTF8')
        d.setdefault(col2, [])
        d[col2].append(col3)
    del d['']
    return d

def find_duplicate():
    #print(d)
    d = get_dict()
    for k,v in d.items():
        if len(v) > 1:
            name=[]
            id=[]
            #print(k)
            for i in v:
                #print(i)
                reg1 = i.split("(")[0]
                name.append(reg1)
                reg2 = re.search(r'[A-Z0-9]*', i.split("_")[1])
                id.append(reg2.group())
            #print(name)
            #print(id)
```

And my index.html is as follows:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col1</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col2</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col3</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col4</th>
            <th bgcolor="#f0a00c">Col5</th>
       </tr>
       {% for b in obj %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ b.col1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ b.col5 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

<script>
        var col21 = [], col31 =[];
        {% for b in obj %}
        col21.push("{{b.col2 }}");
        col31.push("{{b.col3 }}");
        {% endfor %}
        console.log(col21);
        console.log(col31);
    </script>
    </body>
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.display'),
)
```

So, right now the index.html displays the database from mysql ordered by col2 like this:

```
Col2   | Col3                   | Col4
1      | Name1(something_1234)  | Some_date
1      | Name1(something_3456)  | Some_date
2      | Name3(something_7890)  | Some_date
2      | Name4(something_0988)  | Some_date
```

Now, the `get_dict()` function in views.py returns the dictionary `d` which looks as follows:

```
{'1': ['Name1(something_1234)', 'Name1(something_3456)'], '2': 'Name3(something_7890)', 'Name4(something_0988)']}
```

And the `find_duplicate()` function parses the `name` and the `id` part from each element of `Col3`. So `print(name)` in that function will give `names` and `ids` for each `key` (num) i.e., `['Name1', 'Name1']` & `['1234', '3456']` for key `1`.

Now, based on this I want to display red boxes on the table elements as follows:

[image: Table output]

So, for all values in Col2, if any 2 value is same then a box should be displayed around them, and then for that Col2 value check the `name` part and the `id` part and then display boxes around them accordingly.

Right now I'm just able to display the table but how do I display the table along with the boxes around the table elements?

Comment: it sounds more like a JS/CSS solution since I'm not sure how to accomplish this a easy Django way. You could order the qs in separate parts and display them in different `{% for b in obj %}` like having multiple `obj1`, `obj2` and so on and render each one. But I think its easier to write some JS and check for same names etc.

Comment: @hansTheFranz Can you guide me how to do this using JS then? Not much familiar with that. I am getting the col2 & col3 values (which are named as col21, col31 resp) in separate arrays in the html file, if you see the code. What else should I do?

Comment: I have to say I would love to do it but I have the feeling there is a simple solution out there and I would write like 1000 lines of code. I am not the best person when it comes to "good/clean" solutions. If you ask me I would try to find elements with the same name (maybe with regex?) and give each pair a special class. All that would have to be done in a for/while loop to make sure you got all the records (since you never know before how many records you get). So it will be messy if I do it, never worked with tables. Again I'm definitely not the right person to guide you through this.

Comment: I was just searching through SO and did not find anything regarding that topic. I actually think that this is interesting and can't understand why nobody tried it before (or why I'm not able to find it). Maybe you should ask the question without the Django and Python tag, so you don't scare away non Pythonists or you wait, maybe some experienced user will come along and help. I would up vote for sure.

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thanks I'll wait to see if I get any responses.

Comment: glad you got up votes for that new question. I said it was interesting and was a bit confused when I saw that somebody down voted it here....